# Lua: Updating parts of a file hex-editor-style

Tags: file, lua

I try to update certain parts of a file without everything else being deleted or overwritten, however the read/write modes of Lua only seem to support either appending data, or deleting existing data and writing the new one. Here's an example:

testfile.pak: "It's cold outside"  --> "It's warm outside"

Now, I'm dealing with rather big files, not text-files, so reading them into the memory and just using the string manipulation functions are no options here. Also, I'm already processing the files as part of the program, so I don't want to add to the overhead by re-reading them up to the necessary point, insert the data and write the rest. This would require twice as much HDD-space and also twice as much time. I also can't write the necessary data in the first processing cycle. So I'm wondering if it's possible to just tell Lua to write to a certain offset within a file without having to create a temp-file or a duplicate, kind of like a hex-editor is able to change specific portions of files without having to save a whole new copy of the file. Are there other - may be undocumented - write options for io.open other than "w", "w+", "a" and "a+"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with the "r+" mode:

```
~$ cat > test.dat
It's cold outside.
~$ lua
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> f = io.open('test.dat', 'r+')
> f:seek("set", 5)
> f:write("warm")
> f:close()
>
~$ cat test.dat
It's warm outside.
~$
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked great! I wasn't aware that I could still write to a file with opening it in "r+" mode. Also, using the seek command to specify the write position is pretty clever. I was kind of set that it was only used for reading functions.

Comment: Yes, confusingly "r+" is called the "update" mode (which allows you to read what's there, but also to write anywhere). Why they didn't use "u" or something else, I don't know.